# How do I change the position and add a wrapper of a hidden element with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `div` that I have hidden with jQuery. What I want to do is this: I want to show the hidden jQuery element on the far right position instead of the left position where it is hidden in the first place. Besides, I want to give it a new wrapper when I show it on the right.

I am using multiple classes and this one is used for hiding it: `$("div.post.apple").hide();` I want to show this one on the right, wrapped in a new div.

I couldn't find an answer to this. Is this even possible in jQuery and if so, how do I do this?

Comment: Can you try to make it visible and apply wrapper then use some css with jQuery to position it? Or do you love to keep it hidden but a copy of it should be visible on right side?

Comment: Well, the second option would be better, but I am happy with either result.

Comment: can you post what you have so far, and show what you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

In jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var element = $('.post.apple');

  //show element and reposition it
  element.css({
    'right' : '0',
    'left' : 'auto'
  }).show();

  //wrap the element in new container
  element.wrap('<div class="container"></div>');
});
```

You can test it on this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xdvmwxfL/17/

Comment: Almost there, I guess... The problem is that I do not want to click on an element. It has to do it on pageload.. Can you get that working?